# Segmentation fault at function start (C) iff JVM is loaded

Tags: java, c, jvm

I get a segmentation fault (Linux) in some C code.  The crash happens consistently at the same line of code according to `GDB`:

```
void yyparse(void *ptr)
{  <--- Crash happens at this line
```

(This code is old and was working and was generated by `BISON`).

The crash *only* occurs if I have previously loaded a Java virtual machine using the Invocation API.  If I load & destroy the VM before the above line of code is executed then it does *not* crash.  However I need a JVM running so stopping it is not a reasonable
option.

I am baffled on how to debug this problem and would be grateful for some useful
suggestions.

Comment: I think the first step would be to examine the core dump for clues.

Comment: How does the old code behave under valgrind? I am willing to bet that it has existing memory allocation bugs that are now being triggered.

Comment: I've looked at the core dump already.  Apart from telling me where the crash is I can't see anything else helpful.  The backtrace looks OK, for example.

Comment: We have run the code under purify and fixed any issues found there.  The code still crashes.